# Nacha Addenda Record

Tags: flat-file

I am writing some software for generating Nacha files. It's mostly done and working fine. However, one of our clients asked us for an Addenda record (CCD Addenda Record). I am happy to add this, it should be easy but the spec doesn't appear to indicate how the Detail Record (type 6) and the Addenda Record (type 7) are linked. I can't believe its just positional. 
I see a "Entry detail Sequence Number" field on the Addenda record but I don't see a matching number in the Detail Record. There isn't even anything with the same field length. Do any of you know the answer to this?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

your belief is wrong. it is positional. 
Addenda records supply description to their preceding entry.

Answer (score 1):

etwina is mostly correct, but I will add that each addenda record should have the same trace number as its associated entry detail record.